# Ruby on Rails 5 : how to create an web service delivering nested attributes with authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a RoR5 application to provide crypto keys to various applications, through a web service. My RoR application manages Users, and nested Ciphers (using nested attributes). A cipher has a name, and a value (string). Users need to sign in to create Ciphers.

I wish to expose a web service to deliver the requested key:

1 - The client application authenticates (as a user) and provides the Cipher id to the web service

2 - The web service returns the Cipher value

As Ciphers are managed as nested attributes, I a created new dedicated route for this service. Here is the current routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  root   to: 'users#index'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

  get    '/api/:id/', to: 'ciphers#api'
  resources :users

end
```

A specific Ciphers Controller supports the API :

```
class CiphersController < ApplicationController

  #API
  def api
    @cipher = Cipher.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(@cipher.user_id)
    puts @user.nom
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @cipher.cipher_hash}
    end
  end

end
```

The HTML format is available for testing only.
The JSON format actually returns the cipher hash value as expected.

The real question is : How to set up a security and provide user authentication to the service ?

Comment: this is too broad..

Answer (score 0):

The API providing only Json data, there is not authentication form possible. Authentication has to be done through a token passed as request header when calling the API url.

Searching around, I found this resource [Simple token authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication) based on Devise authentication solution.